# How to remove a specific word at the beginning of the content and add it to the end of the content

Tags: functions, the-content

I want to remove any words in the text of posts, before a specific letter (such as :) that comes at the beginning of the text and add that word to the end of the text.

for example:

» Original text

```
        Franky: This is a test.
```

» content after change

```
        This is a test.
        Quote from: Franky
```

Comment: Can you please mark this as the answer if this answered your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this post_content: "Franky: This is a test."

When the post is displayed

Then the post_content is displayed as:

"This is a test.
Quote from: Franky"

There are many, many ways you could do this. I think the best would be to run it through a filter on `the_content` but for sake of simplicity in this example, imaging you have the following where you would normally see `the_content()` in a WordPress template file.

```php
$search_pattern = '@^([^:]+):\s*(.*)$@';
$replace_pattern = '$2<br>' . "\n" . 'Quote: $1';
$new_post_content = preg_replace( $search_pattern, $replace_pattern, get_the_content() );

echo $new_post_content;
```

The reason you should run this through a WordPress filter is that there may be other filters acting on `the_content()` that also modify it (or that will need to modify it *after* your filter).

Also, the exact regular expression will need to be tweaked. I gave an example that assumes that the input is all on one line. If you have multiline input, you'll need to adjust accordingly. How to write regular expressions, however, is another subject so if you need help with that, I would post a separate question.

And finally, to add this to the_content filter, it would be something like this:

```php
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $input ) {
    $search_pattern = '@^([^:]+):\s*(.*)$@';
    $replace_pattern = '$2<br>' . "\n" . 'Quote: $1';
    return preg_replace( $search_pattern, $replace_pattern, $input );
}, 10, 2);
```

And… If you want this modification to support localization, you'll need to run 'Quote from:' through the WordPress translation functions, but that too is a separate question.

Good luck!